# Groupby and find mean of last three instances

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

If I had a dataframe like below:

| cat1 | cat2 | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| A | Y | 2 |
| B | Z | 3 |
| B | M | 4 |
| A | X | 5 |
| A | Y | 6 |
| B | Z | 7 |
| B | M | 8 |
| A | X | 9 |
| A | Y | 10 |
| B | Z | 11 |
| B | M | 12 |

what's the best way to groupby to return a dataframe, to find the mean val for only the last two instances of each (cat1, cat2)?

So for this example we would want:

| cat1 | cat2 | mean_of_last_two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 3 |
| A | Y | 4 |
| B | Z | 5 |
| B | M | 6 |

Comment: The last 2 instances of (A, X) are 5 and 9, why is the mean 3 instead of 7? Can you explain how 3 is calculated?

Comment: Shouldn't the `mean_of_last_two values` column be `[7, 8, 10, 9]` for the last two instances of each (cat1, cat2) listed?

Answer (score 1):

Below code provides mean of last two occurrence, if you need `mean for last 3 then just replace 2 by 3`

**Three options**

**First**

```
df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], as_index=False, sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.tail(2).mean())
```

**Output val col as float**

```
    cat1    cat2    val
0   A       X       7.0
1   A       Y       8.0
2   B       Z       9.0
3   B       M       10.0
```

**Second**

```
grouped = df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'],sort=False)
grouped.nth([-1,-2]).groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], sort=False).val.mean().reset_index()
```

**Third**

```
df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], sort=False).tail(2).groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], sort=False).mean().reset_index()
```

**Output val col as int**

```
    cat1    cat2    val
0   A       X       7
1   A       Y       8
2   B       Z       9
3   B       M       10
```

#### Edit

**Mean of Last 3**

```
df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], sort=False).tail(3).groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], 
    sort=False).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'val':'mean_of_last_three'})

    cat1    cat2    mean_of_last_three
0   A       X       5
1   A       Y       6
2   B       Z       7
3   B       M       8
```

**Mean of Last 2**

```
df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], sort=False).tail(2).groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], 
    sort=False).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'val':'mean_of_last_two'})


        cat1    cat2    mean_of_last_two
0       A       X       7
1       A       Y       8
2       B       Z       9
3       B       M       10
```